# Break javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript script string :

```
var link=C:\test\pictures\myimage\upload\1464592985595_151.jpg
```

I want to get following  **1464592985595_151.jpg**

I am using this to split but getting error in java script

```
link= link.split("\");
```

> **Error:**  unterminated string literal

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: What you have is not a string without quotes...

Comment: i did not get you point

Comment: The thing you posted is not s a string.

Comment: And to get img name, you then could use `var imgName = link.split("\\").pop();`

Answer (score 3):

your link needs to be wrapped in `'` signs like this:

```
var link='C:\test\pictures\myimage\upload\1464592985595_151.jpg';
```

Also, `\` is used to escape characters so you have to escape the escaping:

```
link= link.split("\\");
```

From here it's just a matter of selecting the last piece:

```
console.log(link[link.length -1]; //Outputs '1464592985595_151.jpg'
```

My suggestion to you would be to find a nice coding tool with syntax highlighting like [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to help you catch these things.

Comment: *"you might want to"* -> you have to

Answer (score 0):

Check It .

```
var link="C:/test/pictures/myimage/upload/1464592985595_151.jpg";
var linkarray=link.split("/");
var myimage= linkarray[linkarray.length-1];

alert(myimage);
```

> Note- avoid to use backslash `(\)` in string, because javascript take it
>   as a escape character.